# Working with multidimensional array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
$datas = array(
    array(
        'id' => '1',
        'country' => 'Canada',
        'cities' => array(
            array(
                'city'  => 'Montreal',
                'lang'   => 'french'
            ),
            array(
                'city'  => 'Ottawa',
                'lang'   => 'english'
            )
        )
    )
);
```

## Question 1:

How can I get the the `country` name when I have the `id` ?
I tried: `$datas['id'][1] => 'country'`

## Question 2:

How can I loop in the `cities` when I have the `id` ?
I tried:

```
foreach ($datas as $data => $info) {
    foreach ($info['cities'] as $item) {
        echo '<li>'.$item['city'].'</li>';
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You'll have to iterate over the arrays, fortunately PHP has a range of good array functions. You might want to have a look at `array_filter()`.

Comment: for country echo $datas[0]['country'];

Comment: You have an array inside an array here, so first of all you need to access `$datas[0]` to get to the inner array. _That one_ then has a key `id`. And same for the cities, you want to loop over `$datas[0]['cities']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the ID of the array you want analyse, but your array is structured as a map, meaning that there are no keys in the outer array. You will therefore have to iterate the array first to find the object you are looking for.

While the first approach would be to search for the object that has the ID you are looking for, i suggest you map your arrays with their IDs. To do that, you can use two PHP array functions: `array_column` and `array_combine`.

`array_column` can extract a specific field of each element in an array. Since you have multiple country objects, we want to extract the ID from it to later use it as a key.

`array_combine` takes two arrays with the same size to create a new associative array. The values of the first array will then be used as keys, while the ones of the second array will be used as values.

```
$mappedCountries = array_combine(array_column($datas, 'id'), $datas);
```

Assuming that the key `1` is stored in the variable `$key = 1;`, you can afterwards use `$mappedCountries[$key]['country']` to get the name of the country and `$mappedCountries[$key]['cities']` to get the cities, over which you can then iterate.

Comment: It's working for the question 1. Do you have an example for the question 2 please ?

Comment: @DamDam `$mappedCountries[$key]['cities']` as stated in the answer, over which you then can iterate using `foreach`, like in your code example.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

if there might be many arrays in `$datas` and you want to find one by id (or some other key) you can do something like this:

```
function search($datas, $key, $value) {
    foreach($datas as $data) {
    if ($data[$key] === $value) {
        return $data;   
    }
}
```

So if you want to find where id = 1 
`$result = search($datas, 'id', '1');`
and then you can get country `echo $result['country']` or whatever you need.